# Qt Quick Designer Components module Static Linking not working

Tags: qt, qt6, qt-design-studio

I'm trying to cross compile Qt Quick Designer Components to get QtQuick.Studio.Effects module on Qt 6.5 on arm64 target as I'm getting "module 'QtQuick.Studio.Effects' is not installed" when I try to to run my cross compiled qt application.

So far I have cross compiled Qt Quick Designer Components with help of [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/quick-converting-ui-projects.html) and it outputs libQuickStudioEffects.a static library. I tried to link it in .Pro file by adding the library with qt creator which generated following lines.

`unix:!macx: LIBS += -L/home/user/qt/ -lQuickStudioEffects`

`INCLUDEPATH += /home/user/qt/`
`DEPENDPATH += /home/user/qt/`

`unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += /home/user/qt/libQuickStudioEffects.a`

lib file and executable both are in /home/user/qt/ location in target and host pc.

also I tried with following line.

`LIBS += /home/user/qt/libQuickStudioEffects.a`

So far executable is not detecting the lib file and giving me the above mentioned error. I can run other cross compiled qt6 programs on my target device without any issue. My host runs Ubuntu 20 and target runs on debian 11. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the dev branch from [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/admin/repos/qt-labs/qtquickdesigner-components,branches) and it will give the dynamic QtQuick.Studio.Effects library which can be cross compiled.